# SuiteCRM - Can not Delete or Edit user

Tags: javascript, php, suitecrm

In SugarCRM on admin page I cannot Delete or Edit any user, when I do an inspect on the page I get the following errors

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'return_module' of null
>   at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index.php?module=Users&offset=5&stamp=1505501110089416100&return_module=Users&action=DetailView&record=e78bbaaf-9953-2dd9-f922-596148a73dbe:1295)
>   index.php?module=Users&offset=5&stamp=1505501110089416100&return_module=Users&action=DetailView&record=e78bbaaf-9953-2dd9-f922-596148a73dbe:1295 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'return_module' of null
>   at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index.php?module=Users&offset=5&stamp=1505501110089416100&return_module=Users&action=DetailView&record=e78bbaaf-9953-2dd9-f922-596148a73dbe:1295)

I was upgraded SuiteCRM version 7.7.9 to 7.9.8.

Can anyone guide me?

Comment: did you check suite logs?

Comment: yes, i have checked. but no error log related this javascript issue.

Comment: Can you check the link in the href for the edit and open it directly in another browser?

Comment: suitecrm generates link from javascript based on input tag. <input title="Edit" accesskey="i" name="Edit" id="edit_button" value="Edit" onclick="var _form = document.getElementById('formDetailView');_form.return_module.value='Users'; _form.return_action.value='DetailView'; _form.return_id.value='3c7b8fb7-7f8e-01b3-74f5-5a6642a11194'; _form.action.value='EditView';_form.submit();" type="button">

Comment: share HTML of the page by clicking "view source" and also share metadata (first check 'custom/modules/users/metadata/detailviewdefs.php' OR 'modules/users/metadata/detailviewdefs.php'  )

Comment: moreover have you customized "modules/Users/views.view.detail.php"? if yes then hopefully you have copied it to "custom/modules/Users/views.view.detail.php"? Share custom or core file for debugging.